# Create a network graph using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, graphviz

I am trying to create a network graph using d3.js and I have data about different devices and their links and the interface status(link is up or down).

So, the graph that I have is something like this

```
const data = {
    nodes: [{id: "A"}, {id: "B"}, {id: "C"}],
    links: [{
        source: "A",
        sourceInterface: "link1",
        sourceInterfaceUp: true,
        sink: "B",
        sinkInterface: "link2",
        sinkInterfaceUp: false
    }, {
        source: "B",
        sourceInterface: "link3",
        sourceInterfaceUp: true,
        sink: "C",
        sinkInterface: "link4",
        sinkInterfaceUp: true
    }],
}
```

Could you suggest a ReactJS code to generate a network graph which has nodes(A,B,and C) and vertices(links 1 ,2 ,3 and 4) with names on it for this graph data structure using d3.js

I am looking for something like [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/steveharoz/8c3e2524079a8c440df60c1ab72b5d03)

But in this example I could not figure out how to assign 2 interfaces to the same vertex connecting the devices.
 (A)-------------------------(B)-------------------------(C)

Also, how to include the interface status (`true` or `false`) in the graph.

Any sample code would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use amcharts - network graph/force directed tree which is React compatible and very intuitive as well.

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/force-directed-network/
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/collapsible-force-directed-tree/